# Instanciar clases y ejecutar metodos java desde jsf

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, netbeans, primefaces

Estoy haciendo un webservice, y tengo varios metodos JSF Managed Bean, y necesito instar la clase e invocar los métodos enviándole parámetros tipo `String` desde un formulario JSF page que es de extensión `.xhtml`.

No lo necesito invocar desde un botón, sino que cuando abra el formulario lo haga automáticamente. ¿Que etiqueta puedo usar y donde?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo que entiendo es que quieres que al renderizar tu formulario se haga el llamado de x metodos, ¿es correcto?,   intenta con:
<f:event listener="#{bean.prop}" type="preRenderView" /> , esto lo que hace es invocar un MB y ejecutar el metodo que le indiques esto antes de que se renderice tu xhtml

Comment: Funciona perfecto compañero, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Es muy sencillo, lo que tiene que hacer ya una vez que tienes definido tu Bean es crear un método con la anotación @PostConstruct, esto indica al método que debe de ejecutarse después de la construcción del bean.

```
@ManagedBean(name = "beanEjemplo") 
@SessionScoped
public class Bean{
   private String nombre;

   @PostConstruct
   public void iniciaMensaje(){
      nombre = "Este mensaje se muestra en la vista"
   }

   public void getNombre(){
     return nombre;
   }
   public String setNombre(String nombre){
      this.nombre = nombre;
   }
}
```

ya nada más lo tienes que llamar en tu vista. Espero haber ayudado